# Which pronoun to use for a teacher addressing students

Tags: pronouns

Which pronoun should I use as a teacher when I address my students?

For instance, in this sentence "Please submit **your** essay on Monday"

As far as I know, あなたたち sounds rude

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use a pronoun at all?

Comment: This means that I should avoid using any pronoun? When teachers communicate with the whole class, they don't use any pronoun at all?

Comment: 月曜日に文章を提出してください。←no pronoun. Japanese often omits subjects, so there is no reason you *have* to use a pronoun, whether you're addressing one person or a whole group.

Comment: The primary reason to use a pronoun is to clarify something that would otherwise be ambiguous. If a teacher says to the class to submit an assignment, there shouldn't be any ambiguity as to who is being instructed.

Comment: As already pointed out, omitting subjects is quite natural in Japanese. And personal pronouns are rarely used; if you use one, most of the time, this means you are placing an emphasis on the person(s) it represents. That said, if you have to use a pronoun somehow in the classroom situation you described, 皆さん(more teacher-esque, maybe more natural) or みんな(more informal and friendly) can be used like this way: 皆さん、月曜日に作文を提出してください。 or みんな、月曜に作文を提出してね。